# How to determine what size is required to hold data in a table space?

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm somewhat confused about tablespace and what requirements determines the size needed for it to hold the data.

I have read the documentation, and many articles, including answers here in stackoverflow about tablespace, but I still don't get it.

Let's say I want to create 3 tables:

> - customer
> - product
> - sales

Does the above schema effect the size you choose for your tablespace? or is it completely irrelevant? If it is irrelevant, then what is relevant in this case?

Can someone please explain in simple terms for people who are new to this study.

Comment: What "size" are we talking about?  The size and/ or number of data files assigned to the tablespace?  The extent size within the tablespace (assuming a locally managed tablespace with uniform extent sizes)?  Or are you asking how much space a table takes within a tablespace?  Or something else?

Comment: I'm talking about the size of data files assigned to the tablespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size (and number) of data files assigned to a tablespace depends on the amount of data that you're going to be storing in your tables.  In most organizations, it also depends on what size chunks your storage admins prefer to use, how long it takes to get additional storage space, and other organization-specific bits of information.

Estimating the size of a table can get a bit complicated depending on how close you want to get and how much knowledge you have about your data.  For estimating the size of data files to allocate to a tablespace, though, you can generally get away with a pretty basic estimate and then just monitor actual utilization.

Let's say that your `customer` table has a `customer_id` column that is a numeric identifier, it has a `name` column that averages, say, 30 characters, and a `create_date` that tells you when it was created.  Roughly, that means that every row requires 7 bytes for the `create_date`, 30 bytes for the `name`, lets say an average of 5 bytes for the `customer_id` for a total of 42 bytes.  If we expect to have, say 1,000,000 customers in the first 6 months (we're an optimistic bunch), we'd expect our table to be about 42 MB in size.  If we repeat the process for the other tables in the tablespace and add up the result, that gives us a guess as to how big the data files we'd need to allocate to cover the first 6 months of operation.

Of course, in reality, there are lots of complications.  You can't just add up the size of the columns to get the size of a row.  You'd have to figure out how many rows would be in a block which may depend on patterns of how data changes over time.  I'm ignoring things like `pctfree` that reserve space for future updates to rows.  Plus your estimates for how many rows you're going to have and how big various strings will be are rarely particularly accurate.  So the estimate you're coming up with is **extremely** rough.  In this case, though, even if you're off by a factor of 2, it's not that big of a deal in general.  Once you do the initial allocation, you'll want to monitor how much space is actually used.  So you can always go in later and add files, increase the size of files, etc. if you're using more space than you guessed.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot, just one question, assuming we know the size of the data file needed for the first 6 month, what about the next 6 month?

Comment: @almostabeginner - You could do the same estimation approach.  But since you're monitoring how much space is actually being used over time, it's generally easier to say "today we're using 8 GB.  A month ago we were using 7 GB.  A month from now, we're probably going to need 9 GB".  If you're expecting growth to be faster next month than last month, adjust accordingly.